# Custom routes in CakePHP: regex not limiting matches

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, routes, custom-routes

I'm trying to configure my custom routes in cakephp such that the url

/objects/id/action => ObjectsController.action() with params['id']=id

(This is so that I don't have to have urls like /objects/action/id which logically make less sense to me than objects/id/action).

I still want /objects/action to trigger ObjectsController.action() (e.g. for add, index, search).

My routes config looks like this:

```
Router::connect('/:controller/:id',
    array('action'=>'view'),
    array(
        ':id'       =>  '^[0-9]+$'
    )
);
Router::connect('/:controller/:id/:action/*',
    array('action'=>'view'),
    array(
        ':id'       =>  '^[0-9]+$',
        ':action'   =>  '[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*'
    )
);
```

This works with (for example):

- /objects/54
- /objects/54/edit
- /objects/add

But not with

- /objects/index/page:2

For which it gives me the error that I need to define the action "page:2" in ObjectsController... Surely it should work, because :id should only match digits, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove ":" from second param:

```
'id'       =>  '^[0-9]+$'
```

Also see 'pass' option.

@see google on "cakephp routes":

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration

Comment: This is funny. I actually came on here after I realised how incredibly stupid I'd been (I was adding a new route at the time and it twigged).

Thanks very much.